# Set fullscreen mode by default

Tags: block-editor

The block editor has a `Fullscreen mode` which you can access via the tools options on the top-right:

[image]

Is there a PHP approach to enable the `Fullscreen mode` by default? As in, force this mode for all users. Alternatively, a javascript solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switching Gutenberg to fullscreen mode requires setting to TRUE `fullscreenMode` from the `core/edit-post` package. To enqueue appropriate script, you use `enqueue_block_editor_assets` action hook.

```
function se337302_fullscreen_editor()
{
    $js_code = "jQuery(document).ready(function(){" .
            "   var isFullScreenMode = wp.data.select('core/edit-post').isFeatureActive('fullscreenMode');" .
            "   if ( !isFullScreenMode )" .
            "       wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').toggleFeature('fullscreenMode');" .
            "});";
    wp_add_inline_script( 'wp-blocks', $js_code );

}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'se337302_fullscreen_editor' );
```

Comment: Beautiful. I learned a lot with this one, thank you!

Comment: So dirty, but still useful. :)

Comment: Good [thread](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/03/03/fullscreen-mode-enabled-by-default-in-the-editor/) about this on the WP core blog.